# Cron failing on Update Membership Statuses and Send Renewal Reminders

Tags: drupal, civimember, cron

We're running Civicrm 4.7.11, Drupal 7.56 on Cpanel.

I'm running cron via a custom php script that calls the url as per the civicrm cookbook.

All the jobs seem to get called except "Update Membership Statuses and Send Renewal Reminders" which fails with:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function delete() on null in /home/sitename/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php on line 659
```

Same error happens when running from drush, and when trying to execute manually via admin page I get a WSOD 500 error, which i guess is the same problem.

The issue seems to have occurred when moving to a new cpanel server which is using easyapache PHP instead of Cloudlinux.

Any ideas? PHP error? Civicrm? Drupal?

I've been holding off updating Civicrm due to a Leaflet maps issue with drupal.

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue with the help of xurizaemon on the Mattermost chat channel.

The script was failing because it was trying to delete a membership that looked like it was already deleted.

Hints below:

> so "call to member function delete() on null" means that CiviCRM
>   expected there to be an object and called a method on it - but the
>   object didn't exist
>
> i'd guess that
>   here(https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php#L631)
>   Civi tried to fetch a membership
>
> then
>   here(https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php#L665)
>   Civi tried to delete the membership
>
> but it didn't look to see if the first thing failed - and so when it
>   tries to call delete on null, it falls over.
>
> IMO it makes sense to inspect the result of line 631 before it treats
>   it as an object
>
> ie if ($membership = $memberships[$membershipId]) { /* do all the
>   stuff with $membership */ }
>
> or (easier to read) if (!$membership = $memberships[$membershipId]) {
>   /* bail out / throw exception */ }

So I downloaded a DB dump to a dev environment. Checked the error was still there.

Then ran the task from the scheduled tasks page. With a vardump in the membership.php script just after the lines noted above.

var_dump($membership);

and then

var_dump($membershipID);

The memberships in the dump were both linked to the same parent membership, so I deleted that parent membership and recreated it from scratch.

Membership scheduled task is now running as usual.

I think the db may have been corrupted a bit on a recent server move.

Comment: We fixed this through this process but it since came back after new memberships. Did this happen to you? Any ideas on fixing this? Thanks